# What is the best way to save a real-time dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I need to use Python to do a lot of commands on a system, and at the same time save in a dataframe everything that is being done.

In this situation, how do you deal with the risk of problems during execution that terminate the application abruptly?

When I add data in a dataframe from the Pandas library, is it still only a variable during execution, and if there is a problem is the variable completely lost along with its data.

Answer (score 1):

If your program crashes you will lose all your data. The best way to avoid this is to save your data every X seconds/minutes so you can have a backup if something goes wrong.

Here is a little example :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("big_file")

for x in range(100000):
    # Lots of operations
    # Every one thousand loop we save the data in case the program crashes
    if np.mod(i,1000) == 0:
        df.to_csv('backup_{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Comment: You could pickle your dataframe in memory as part of error handling. You could have another process within your operations write a log file similar to the backup idea which keeps an index of where you're at.  This would work as a history but keeps a real-time backup rather than an iterative data dump

Comment: Once completed, all of this needs to go to Microsoft SQL Server database. In these suggestions, what would be the best format to save and then export to SQL? .csv, .xls or other?